# Precalculate component in react native

Tags: react-native

I have a piece of components which will be rendered after a user click on a button. However, these components involving too many calculation. It takes 3~5 seconds to complete it.
I want to compute it in advance and store into my state.
So I can show it on the fly.

But somehow, the content always returns null to my state.

Any idea? 
[image: inline]

```
        prepopulateDetail(){
            let displayedSources = {}
            this.setState({setState: (
                <View>
                    {
                        [... new Set(this.props.definition)].map(wordDef => {
                            if (wordDef.content.length >= 0 && displayedSources.hasOwnProperty(wordDef.source) === false) {
                                displayedSources[wordDef.source] = true
                                return (
                                    <View style={styles.definitions} key={guid()} i={wordDef.source}>
                                        <Badge containerStyle={{
                                            backgroundColor: PRIMARY_BG,
                                            width: 100,
                                            marginTop: 5,
                                            marginBottom: 5,
                                            borderRadius: 0
                                        }}>
                                            <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>{wordDef.source.toUpperCase()}</Text>
                                        </Badge>
                                        {
                                            wordDef.content.map((content, j) => {
                                                let data = JSON.parse(content)
                                                return this.displayWordDefinition(data)
                                            })
                                        }
                                    </View>

                                )
                            }

                        })
                    }
                </View>
            )}, this.showState)
        }
```

Comment: Why are you storing JSX in the component state?!

Comment: the JSX part contains heavy compoutation

Comment: Do the computation, set the results to state and have the state change update your jsx...I don't think you're approaching it the right way.